# Drupal #ajax callback executing twice

Tags: 7, ajax, forms

I am creating a custom paginator in Drupal 7.

The paginator is working fine, the only problem is that every time I click to the next page button, increases the step in 2 (For example I can see pages 0,2,4,6,etc...)and that's because the submit button is executed twice and increases the number of the page by two.

As you can see in the callback I use AJAX to replace two different sections on the page, and that might be the cause.

Any idea?

Submit function:

```
function club_paginator_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
$values = $form_state['values'];

if ($form_state['triggering_element']['#value'] == '>')
{
    $form_state['values']['current_page'] = intval($form_state['values']['current_page'])+1;
}
else
{
    $form_state['values']['current_page'] = intval($form_state['values']['current_page'])-1;
}

$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
```

}

Forms:
(...)

```
$form['next'] = array(
    '#name' => 'paginator-next',
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('>'),
    '#weight' => 5,
    "#ajax" => array(
        "callback" => "ajax_club_paginator_next",
        "effect" => "fade",
    ),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="club-paginator-page-replace">'.$page.'</div>',
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('button')),
    '#submit' => array('club_paginator_form_submit'),
);
```

(...)

Callback:

```
function ajax_club_paginator_next($form, &$form_state)
{
    $page = intval($form_state['values']['current_page']);

    $html = '';
    $html .= '<div id="club-paginator-content-replace">';
    $html .= draw_clubes_page($page);
    $html .= '</div>';

    $paginator = '<div id="paginator">';
    $form = drupal_get_form('club_paginator_form', $page);
    $paginator .= drupal_render($form);
    $paginator .= '</div>';

    return array(
        '#type' => 'ajax',
        '#commands' => array(
            ajax_command_replace("#club-paginator-content-replace", $html),
            ajax_command_replace("#paginator", $paginator)
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more info? Such us paginator mockup?

Comment: When you remove one of the commands do you still have to problem of incrementing the value by 2?

Comment: No. That's the problem. I have to find another place to put the submit logic

Comment: (UPDATE) apparently yes. I don't know if there's some cache... It seemed to worked once but know it has the same workflow.

Comment: (UPDATE 2) drupal_get_form('club_paginator_form', $page); is calling the second submit logic. Any idea on how to stop that?

Answer (score 1):

I Finally found the error...

drupal_get_form was calling the submission again, I was creating a new form like the one I was substituing, but I was also updating the old.

Instead of creating a new form, I just used the $form variable instead of drupal_get_form.

Please find the new logic below!

```
function ajax_club_paginator_next($form, &$form_state)
{
    $page = intval($form_state['values']['current_page']);

    $html = '';
    $html .= '<div id="club-paginator-content-replace">';
    $html .= draw_clubes_page($page);
    $html .= '</div>';

    $paginator = '<div id="paginator">';

    //Not Needed!
    //$form = drupal_get_form('club_paginator_form', $page);

    $paginator .= drupal_render($form);
    $paginator .= '</div>';

    return array(
        '#type' => 'ajax',
        '#commands' => array(
            ajax_command_replace("#club-paginator-content-replace", $html),
            ajax_command_replace("#paginator", $paginator)
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Xavi's excellent answer to his question...

watch out for unnecessary use of drupal_get_form within an ajax callback function

e.g.

```
function your_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  $commands = array();
  $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('#result', drupal_render(drupal_get_form('your_form')['result']));
  return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
}
```

It is only necessary to use drupal_get_form in the above callback if you need to deal with a different form from the one invoking the callback. If that's not the case, stick to the version below

```
function your_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  $commands = array();
  $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('#result', drupal_render($form['result']));
  return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
}
```